# C++ recommendet way of declaring RAII type (unique_lock)

Tags: c++, syntax

Today I stumbled accross a nasty bug in our code:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> (some_mutex);
```

Notice the missing identifier. I was surprised this actually compiled and translates to:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> some_mutex;
```

It creates a default constructed unique_lock with the same name as the mutex, which is ok since in this case `some_mutex` is in another scope. Turns out the type identifier can be put into parentheses simply for function ptrs to work. I thought this is simply fixed by using brace initialization:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> {some_mutex};
```

But this just creates a temporary object. This makes brace initialization actually more dangerous for RAII types since it'll work on classes without a default constructor, too:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> {some_mutex};
```

Ofcourse this all comes down to a missing identifier but could still cause extremely hard to find bugs. What is the recommendet way of declaring a RAII type to avoid this nasty corner case?

Edit:

I'm well aware how to use RAII classes. The point is: In case you forget the identifier you'll probably never notice it, since you normally won't use the identifier again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can suggest is to have a function with pragma/attribute "must use return".
That way `make_unique_lock(my_mutex);` would generate a warning that you are not using the returned value, but `auto locker = make_unique_lock(my_mutex);` would work as desired.
However, `if (make_unique_lock(my_mutex))` would also be legal, and might immediately destroy the temporary, also. Perhaps you could block that by deleting `operator bool()&&`

However, last time I looked, unique_lock banned all copy/move semantics, so it can't be used in this way...
Until c++17, which allows return value elision even in the absence/deletion of copy and move members, so perhaps this would work in c++17?

```
template <class Mutex>  [[nodiscard]]
std::unique_lock<Mutex> make_unique_lock(Mutex& m)
{
    return m;
}
```

In C++11 probably the best you could do is to call that same method with `auto& locker = make_unique_lock(myMutex);` to avoid the blocked assignment, but keeping the temporary alive by taking the reference. Of course in c++11 you would have to use a vendor attribute instead of [[nodiscard]].

Note that this approach benefits with auto deduction of the template arg, so is actually simpler than the traditional declaration!

This is all semi-untested talk.

More top-of-the-head: If you could decorate the constructor with `[[nodiscard]]` with the special meaning that you can't *discard* the constructed object without naming it, then you get exactly the behaviour you want!

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is:

```
std::mutex some_mutex;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> my_lock(some_mutex);
```

I see no ambiguity or corner-cases here. Anonymous (temporary) objects are of no use when it comes to RAII since they are destroyed immediately. So, give it a name and pass in your mutex.

Comment: ofcourse this is how you are supposed to use these RAII types. But you can easily forget the identifier and never notice since you are not supposed to use it for anything. In that case the bug pretty much goes unnoticed

Comment: I know of no better way. C++ is not really in the business of protecting users from their own mistakes. I suppose you could write `auto my_lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(some_mutex)` (which will fail if you "forget" the `my_lock` identifier) but... _really?_

Comment: Normally RAII type identifiers are very short: `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> g(some_mutex);` & `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> (some_mutex)` I think in this case it can really easily slip through once in a while. Your solution won't work on types with deleted copy ctors. So I guess using some type of static analyser & being careful is the best you can do

Comment: "C++ is not really in the business of protecting users from their own mistakes" - I beg to differ - all these new-fangled shared_ptr, etc, are all about giving the user a false sense of security :-)